# Is the time between two questions allowed to be posted constant?

Tags: bug, questions, badges

I ve just started to participate and I have to wait 40 minutes since my last question to post another. 
Will it be 40 minutes for the rest of my life on superuser or does the waiting time Change with earned Points? If so, when can I expect my time to be lowered at the earliest?

Comment: I highly encourage you to slow down on the number of questions you are asking.  Focus on the questions you have currently, improve those questions, get the answers you seek before asking additional questions

Comment: thank you for your advice, I will concentrate more on the depth and Quality of my questions, at least as good as I can.

Answer (score 3):

As per the *[complete rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)* on meta.se, which references back to [this lovely post on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore/322265#322265) - you're limited until you hit 125 reputation.

Its a feature, not a bug